# How to add item to a list<object> from database in C#?

Tags: c#, list, object

I'm creating a `list <object>` and here I'm adding my data from a database.

But I totally don't know how to deal with a `list <object>`.

```
public class ClassList
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
}

private void GetClassList()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GlobalVar.ConnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
        ("SELECT * " +
         "FROM Class_Data ", conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        List<ClassList> ClassList = new List<ClassList>();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ClassList.Add(new ClassList()
            {
                Name = ___?___, //what should i write here
                Birthday = ___?___ //and here
            });
        }
     }
    catch{}
    finally
    {
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Having been looking for lots of information but still fail to work it out.

I will be very appreciated if someone could help!

Comment: Side note: `catch{}` - swallowing all the exception is a very bad and dangerous practice

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
List<ClassList> ClassList = new List<ClassList>();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            ClassList.Add(new ClassList()
            {
                Name = (int)dr["Name"], //the name of the db column
                Birthday = dr["Birthday"].ToString();
            });
        }
```

As a side note, it maybe worth altering your query from `SELECT *...` to just selecting the columns you require, from readability/maintenance point of view.

Also, is `Name` really an `int` seems like it could be a `string`.

You can also refer to the documentation:

[SqlDataReader.Item Property (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Where `Name` and `Birthday` are the column names in your database, you want to read.

Comment: @Ric But there are several students information in my database. It always throw an Exception.

Comment: what exception is being thrown? if there are multiple rows being returned this shouldn't cause an issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use column name that are return by your database query with `dr` like `dr["ColumnName"]`

```
 ClassList.Add(new ClassList()
 {
         Name = dr["NameColum"], //what should i write here
         Birthday = dr["BrithColum"] //and here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
// You don't use "this" in the context
// It seems, that you want to return the collected data (List<ClassList>)
private static List<ClassList> GetClassList() {
  // Put IDisposable into using 
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GlobalVar.ConnString)) {
    conn.Connect();

    // You want to fetch two fields only, right? Not the entire table (*)
    String sql = 
      @"select Name,
               BirthDay
          from Class_Data"

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
      List<ClassList> result = new List<ClassList>();

      using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (dr.Read()) {
          result.Add(new ClassList() {
            Name = Convert.ToString(dr[0]),
            Birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[1])
          });
        }
      }  

      return result;  
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the column values with `dr["ColumnName"]`.